# How can get real time data from an HttpClient request in Angular 6

Tags: angular, apache, caching, httpclient, angular6

I've got this problem on my Angular 6 App. I need to have always fresh data from a HttpClient request.

I'm calling a service for retrieve data from a json file on server filesystem:

```
this.testDataService.retrieveConfig().subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log("test -> ", response);
      this.testDataService.initConfig(response);
      this.config = this.testDataService.getTest();
    },
    error => {
      console.log("Error",error);
    }
  );
```

That seems to be good, but the problem is that, in my built app, everytime I call get method, (it is verified in my console.log into subscribe arrow function) the response doesn't change even than I change my json file informations. This not happen on my local angular-cli enviroment. It's not a solution for change the informations is clean the browser cache. Not works restart web server (apache) or refresh page with CTRL+F5.

I've not yet understood if the problem is Angular call o Web server configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: This might be a caching problem.. Can you please post the code of retrieveConfig() function? Try adding a timestamp  qyerystring to the resource you are requesting.

Comment: You can make use of valuechanges() on the observable. This will create a websocket and poll if the data of the retrieveConfig is changed. And if will excute the responce function.

Comment: A quick way to do this is to add the current timestamp as a param to your query: `path/to/api?t=1538041780`

Comment: Adding timestamp info into uri the problem is solved. I Thank you All!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (workaround) is how menthioned by Ritesh before, and Ploppy after, to add a timestamp information into URI for make "unique" every request.

I Thank you all!